# How do I go about making a settings menu with MVVM in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to make a settings menu for my card game (black jack) in wpf. For most settings, a TextBox would be sufficient, but for others, a checkbox, datepicker or something more complex would be preferable.
Without MVVM, I would have simply hard-coded all settings into one usercontrol, but with MVVM, as far as I understand it, the view shouldn't know what options there are, and the model/viewmodel shouldn't care about how the settings are displayed...

So far, I've only created a class which represents an option (setting)

```
    public class Option<T>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public T DefaultValue { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The current value
        /// </summary>
        public T Value { get; set; }

        public Option(string name, T defaultValue)
        {
            Name = name;
            DefaultValue = defaultValue;
            Value = defaultValue;
        }

        public Option(string name, T defaultValue, T value) : this(name, defaultValue)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Resets the value to default
        /// </summary>
        public void Reset() => Value = DefaultValue;
    }
```

But now, there's also the problem that I can't have a list of options, only a list of options that have a specific type... I guess the solution for this would be replacing `T` with `object`?

I've also created a usercontrol (view) called `OptionBase` which contains the stuff all options contain (a textblock displaying the name of the option, some interactable element(s) for adjusting the setting, a button for saving the change, and a button for resetting the settings to it's default value):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
           FontSize="50"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

<ContentControl Grid.Column="1"
                Content="{Binding Option}"/>

<Button Grid.Column="2"
        Content="OK"
        FontWeight="Light"
        Command="{Binding ConfirmCommand}"/>

<Button Grid.Column="3"
        Content="↻"
        Command="{Binding ResetCommand}"/>
```

The `ContentControl` is supposed to contain some interactable element(s) for actually adjusting the option.
So then I was planning on creating multiple option views like TextBoxOption which would just contain an OptionBase element but would put a textbox into the content of the contentcontrol through a property on the OptionBase control I guess.
However, the problem still remains: Where do I specify which option view should be used by which option view model?

I've been thinking about this for a few hours now and I feel like I'm overcomplicating this. I'm so lost now...

Comment: Without knowing the options how should the view present what it does not know. That does not make sense. The View knows the ViewModel and anything beyond but the ViewModel does not know anything about the View.

Comment: You could use [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector) to edit your options based on their type. I don't think using generics is going to help in this scenario. You are better off writing a base Option class and create child Option classes based on the data you want to edit.

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville Thank you for the idea. However, I don't know how having a base option class would work. All options have a default value and the current value, and for different options, these properties need to store different types (e.g. int/DateTime...). You can't change the type of a property from the base class when deriving from it, can you? What do you think about replacing `T` with `object`?

Comment: @SirRufo I see, thank you... I guess I will just put all the options I need straight onto the view then. I don't know why, but it seemed wrong to me.

Comment: Well, you should have a ViewModel which holds the values and the View has the control to edit these values from the ViewModel. That is the way to go

Comment: @SirRufo right, ofc... Thanks!